# SQL query returning only some rows

Tags: sql

Need help with an sql query.

Table:

**user      day           type     value** 
john     monday cleaner  0 
john     monday cleaner  1 
peter  monday cleaner  1 
mark  monday cleaner  1 
mark  monday cleaner  0

I want the query to return the rows that have the value field > 0 but if there is a row that as user day and type with value 0 no row is returned.
In this case only "peter monday cleaner 1" row is returned because there is a "john monday cleaner" with value 0 and 1 and a mark too.

Thanks

Comment: Let's see the SQL query you used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I have understood from your requirement description this is the query you need.

```
select * from table a where a.value>0 
// This returns all rows that have values equal to 1. In your case
       john   monday cleaner 1 
       peter  monday cleaner 1 
       mark   monday cleaner 1


  and a.user not in
   (select b.user from table b where b.value=0)

// This would check that the users in the above 3 rows do not have any rows in the 
   result of the select with value =0

       john   monday cleaner 0 
       mark   monday cleaner 0 

//Here it has 2 rows with value = 0 and "and a.user not in" would esnure that from 
//the first 3 rows, only those users are selected who are not fetched in the 2 rows 
//given above.
```

So when you run the query

```
select * from table a where a.value>0   
 and a.user not in
(select b.user from table b where b.value=0)

peter  monday cleaner 1  // Result.
```

I guess, thats exactly what u need.

Comment: spoke too soon, it only works for the first match. If several rows with the same condition exist, user day and type fields equal with 0 and 1 as value, it shows the row with value 1

Comment: Can you update the question with such rows.

Comment: From what i understand, for the same combination of the first three columns, if the value column has two values(0 and 1), you dont show it. But if it has only value 1, show it. correct me if i am wrong

Comment: So from the above data, you only need 1 row .Since both mark and john have two rows but one of them has 0 and only peter has rows with value only 1 .Right ?

Comment: yes, only the peter row with value 1 should be shown

Comment: @user3022110 The query returns just that.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM Table as a WHERE a.value > 0 AND EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Table as b WHERE b.user=a.user AND b.value=0)
```

If you want the same row with different numbers to only show up once you could use:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.user, a.day, a.type FROM Table as a WHERE a.value > 0 AND EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Table as b WHERE b.user=a.user AND b.value=0)
```

Comment: Shouldnt it be not exists ? He only wants to display rows with value >0 if there are no rows with value=0

Comment: I understood he only wanted the rows that also have a version with value 0

Comment: This one: "SELECT * FROM Table as a WHERE a.value > 0 AND EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Table as b WHERE b.user=a.user AND b.value=0)" shows "john   monday cleaner 1" and "peter  monday cleaner 1" the idea is to only return "peter  monday cleaner 1"

Comment: no data is returned with not exists

Answer (score 0):

```
select _user,_day,_type,MAX(_Value)
    from #tmp
    GROUP BY _user,_day,_type
    having COUNT(*) = 1
```